# Razor: Class name is not valid at this point

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I was simply trying to list products on the main page. Here's how I'm doing it....

```
@using iShop.Controllers
@using iShop.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <p>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var p in Product) { }
                    <li>@p.Title</li>
                }
            </ul>
    </p>
```

I'm getting the error "Class name is not valid at this point." The issue is with "Product" in the foreach. Any idea why? iShop.Models.Product does exist.

Comment: You have not declared a model in the view, and assuming its `@model IEnumerable<Product>` then it needs to be `@foreach (var p in Model)` assuming you have passed a collection of `Product` to the view in your GET method

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple `Product` in a list form being passed as a View, simple. you will add one more thing here,

> you are not going to get intellisence support or a strongly typed view page here

To get it do it this way. Just add a reference of the model by using  the IEnumerable interface `@model IEnumerable<Product>` and you are done.

So,in the view page  `@model IEnumerable<Product>` then it needs to be `@foreach (var p in Model)` assuming you have passed a collection of Product to the `controller` particular action method

[Various Ways to Pass Data From Controller to View in MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/)

Answer (score 0):

add @model IEnumerable < Product > to the top of your page....also remember to change (var p in Product) to (var p in Model) as you bind Product model to your view.